# No difference between PUT and PATCH in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here are my simple viewset and serializer classes:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

....    

class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Suppose I want to update only my user's first name. In that case, I should use `PATCH` `{"first_name": "New First Name"}`. But at the same time, it looks like that `PUT` `{"first_name": "New First Name"}` also works the same way, though it shouldn't, because it has to validate that all the fields are specified. At least I thought so. Am I wrong? And if I'm, then what is the difference between `update` and `partial_update` in Django Rest Framework and is there any reason to keep them both (since any additional method implies additional testing, so the latter question is a bit philosophical, because looks like people find this PUT/PATCH pair really confusing). By the way, I'm using `djangorestframework==3.8.2`. Thank you.

Comment: Does this behaviour only for ***`User`*** model?

Comment: No, the actual model doesn't matter.

Comment: This explains that behavior better: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3648

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the generated serializer, you'll find that you don't have required fields. In that case, PUT and PATCH will have similar behavior.
Would there be any required field, you'd see the difference.

```
serializer = UserSerializer(instance=user, data={"first_name": "New First"})
print(serializer)                                                                                                                                                                                  

    UserSerializer(data={'first_name': 'New First'}, instance=<User: tester>):
        id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
        email = EmailField(allow_blank=True, label='Email address', max_length=254, required=False)
        first_name = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=30, required=False)
        last_name = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=150, required=False)
```

Comment: Hm, but according to the documentation, all fields are `required=True` by default.

Comment: When you explicitly define them without providing an explicite `required=False`. For autogenerated fields from a model, things are a bit different.

Comment: This is implemented at https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py#L100-L101

Comment: The file @Linovia was pointing to has changed, here is a permalink to the right place: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/c5d9144aef1144825942ddffe0a6af23102ef44a/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py#L104-L105