# Django Rest Framework not showing form fields for PATCH/PUT request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project that is using Django Rest Framework. For some reason, when I go to one of my endpoints (to make a PATCH/PUT request), I am not seeing any of the form fields in the browsable API. Here is the code for the resource:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Patient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    primary_doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor', related_name='patients', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    born_on = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0.first_name} {0.last_name}".format(self)
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from ..models.patient import Patient
from ..serializers import PatientSerializer


class Patients(APIView):
    def get(sef, request):
        patients = Patient.objects.all()[:10]
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patients, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    serializer_class = PatientSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        patient = PatientSerializer(data=request.data)
        if patient.is_valid():
            patient.save()
            return Response(patient.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(patient.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class PatientDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=pk)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patient)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    serializer_class = PatientSerializer

    def patch(self, request, pk):
        patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=pk)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patient, data=request.data['patient'])
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk)
        patient.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models.patient import Patient


class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'diagnosis', 'born_on', 'primary_doctor', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views.doctor_views import Doctors, DoctorDetail
from .views.patient_views import Patients, PatientDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('doctors/', Doctors.as_view(), name='doctors'),
    path('doctors/<int:pk>/', DoctorDetail.as_view(), name='doctor_detail'),
    path('patients/', Patients.as_view(), name='patients'),
    path('patients/<int:pk>/', PatientDetail.as_view(), name='patient_detail'),
]
```

This is what the browser looks like when I go to '/patients/3'. There are no form fields to fill out, only a content area for JSON. When I go to POST at '/patients', the form fields appear and I can POST fine.
Could anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: can you also please share the url patterns for the endpoints?

Comment: @twrought Yes I have added them to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `PatientDetail`'s `patch` method to `put`, the form should appear and function properly at the url to update a patient. You can use them somewhat interchangeably with DRF, to my understanding ([No difference between PUT and PATCH in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079614/no-difference-between-put-and-patch-in-django-rest-framework)). The difference lies in whether the serializer fields are required or not.

Though, they are technically different things at a low level - patch being a real 'partial update' ([Use of PUT vs PATCH methods in REST API real life scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/use-of-put-vs-patch-methods-in-rest-api-real-life-scenarios)).

In the `put` method, you also should change

```
serializer = PatientSerializer(patient, data=request.data['patient'])
```

to

```
serializer = PatientSerializer(data=request.data)
```

Then, the endpoints should behave as expected.